# VTK model animation

Tags: animation, model, xtk

First of all .. congratulations on creating such an awesome library for the community.

I've been looking at XTK for examples on how to load up scenegraph files and more importantly for our application, how to visualization VTK model animations. Is there support for these features yet ?

Thanks much,

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible already by adding all vtk files and setting the visibility to false. Then, in the onRender callback, show one and keep track of which one is shown and which are hidden. If you are able to share data, I would be happy to take a look!

Comment: That's great and thanks. Currently the data is in NetCDF format and I'm almost done writing the VTK converter. I can send you a link to download it from soon.